# How to grep certain attribute from openldap?

Tags: command-line, grep, openldap

I am using openldap and usually I will use command `ldapsearch uid=<ldap> +` to check certain attribute and by running such command, it will produce full output for example :

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
lastLoginTime: 20220829012233Z
passwordRetryCount: 0
retryCountResetTime: 20220826111616Z
passwordExpWarned: 0
passwordExpirationTime: 20220905092802Z
pwdUpdateTime: 20220707092802Z
modifyTimestamp: 20220707092802Z
```

If, for example I would like to grep only "retryCountResetTime", I try to run :

```
ldapsearch uid=<ldap> + | grep ^retryCountResetTime
```

But the output will be :

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
retryCountResetTime: 20220826111616Z
```

I would like to remove the first 3 line (SASL) by adding tail -1, but it doesn't work.

Any suggestion how can I remove the line 1-3?

Comment: Perhaps the first 3 lines are not going to the standard output stream at all, but to the standard error stream?

Comment: In other words :) have you tried this: `ldapsearch uid=<ldap> + 2>/dev/null | grep ^retryCountResetTime`?

Comment: Thank you @pa4080 ! It works!

Comment: You are welcome, @msmystic. I've converted the comments into an answer. You could accept it if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) mentioned within the [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426365/how-to-grep-certain-attribute-from-openldap?noredirect=1#comment2483872_1426365):

> Perhaps the first 3 lines are not going to the standard output stream at all, but to the standard error stream?

To verify that you can redirect the STDERR channel to some other *place*, for example the null device by adding `2>/dev/null` at the end of the command:

```bash
command -options arguments 2>/dev/null | grep 'something'
```

If you want to process it you can redirect it to STDOUT by adding `2>&1`:

```bash
command -options arguments 2>&1 | grep 'something'
```

Note if you want to redirect STDERR along with STDOUT to a file the syntax is:

```bash
command -options arguments >/path/to/some.log 2>&1
```